# iostream and sstream for Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c++

I'm trying to port some C++ code to Objective-C. It includes `iostream` and `sstream`, but Objective-C does not recognize these. What should be done?

Comment: Ask another, very similar question on stackoverflow 6 minutes after this one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `iostream` and `sstream` in Objective-C++.

Just make sure your source code file ends with `.mm` instead of `.m` and you will be able to use any standard C++ library you might need. Including `<stream>`.