# Trying to do c++ in objective-c: can't find iostream.h?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

trying `#include "iostream"` but `iostream` is not found, but `stdio.h` works fine.

What am I missing?

Tried using: [iostream and sstream for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794931/iostream-and-sstream-for-objective-c)

Same errors even when converting file extension to ".mm"

Tried: ['iostream' file not found error occur in xcode 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376525/iostream-file-not-found-error-occur-in-xcode-4-5)

No good as well.

and... [Usage of C++ in Objective C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073989/usage-of-c-in-objective-c)

Comment: That's not a standard header.

Comment: @jdl Use #include <iostream>

Comment: @Vlad... now I get "iostream" not found

Comment: @jdl Did you indeed write <iostream> and not "iostream"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Using quotation marks is required to "try angle brackets" if the lookup fails.

Comment: @vlad YES both ways.

Comment: #include "iostream"  ... <iostream>  neither work

Comment: @jdl Do you run a C++ program or C program?

Comment: I am trying to write c++ in objective-c(mac)

Comment: @jdl Are you sure that the compiler compiles it as a C++ program?

Comment: objective-c asks what kind of file to create... c++ is a choice.  Also, with in the file I can write "class" and it sets up a c++ class template... just fill in the blanks...its great.  So I know it knows c++.  I just want to include header files so I can do basic stuff like "cout" etc for now.

Comment: @jdl I did not deal with this compiler and its IDE so unfortunately I can say nothing more.

Comment: @jdl are you using xcode?

Comment: @jdl can you look at your source code file and check if it is a `.m` file?

Comment: Any luck on that issue, I have an old code which worked alright with Xcode 9.x but give issue with Xcode 10.